# How to convert a math expression into sums of factors programmatically?

Tags: c#, math, mathematical-optimization, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm dealing with a tricky **legacy calculation system**.

It's so finicky that you can't just tell it to calculate `a+b*c`. Instead, you need to send it as:

```
{ a }
{ b, c }
```

Concretely, in C#, the calculation is a list of sums of factors expressed like this:

```
var calculationRequest = new List<string[]> 
{ 
    new [] { "a" },
    new [] { "b", "c" },
};

var result = calculator.Calculate(calculationRequest);
```

## How does it work?

What it does is to multiply the variables in each row, and the it sums all the rows.

The problem I have is that I would like to create an algorithm to convert an expression into the structure that the legacy system needs.

For now, I have created a parser that turns every expression into a tree of operations.

For example `a+b*c` turns into

[image]

But how to convert this tree into the structure required by the legacy system? This is, how to convert the AST into a list of sums of factors?

I'm completely stuck.

## ADDITIONAL INFO

The legacy system can process subtractions and divisions adding a "-" or "/" before each identifier.

For instance, `a-b` would turn into

```
{ a }
{ -b }
```

and `a+(b/c)` would turn into

```
{ a }
{ b, /c }
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I've created a parser that converts expressions into an AST. It's in the question.

Comment: if you've already created the parser then where is the problem?

Comment: Can you publish the parser and the attempt in which you handle the legacy system processing? The thing is, nobody will guess how you started up your work, you shall explain the bottleneck of **a** solution, not the solution (not yet implemented) as the bottleneck

Comment: @Shmwel https://github.com/SuperJMN/Simple-Formula-Parser. It's called SemiFullParser.

Comment: @Shmwel the bottleneck is well explained in the question: having the AST, how to create the list of sums of factors?

Comment: **make internet a better place** - *That means that a primary characteristic of a good question is that it is likely to be searched by someone else.* ... and your question is too narrow to your only problem

Comment: @SuperJMN can you have multiple  levels for an expression? (e.g. a+(b/(c/(d\*e))) - if yes, how do you plan to represent them? Honestly, the answer for your problem is pretty obvious: you attach a depth property to each level and for each i-th depth you simply perform the operations (then sum up each level). To make the things easier to understand I suggest to create a very basic simple example and show where the bottleneck is in the code.This question is more like a "design" related task

Comment: To sum up what `@Shmwel` has said, there is currently no way to completely reproduce the *recursive structure* of an AST, especially when it comes to divisions.

Comment: Nobody is ridiculing you, people are asking what you've tried so far and where you are stuck. If your question is _"how to convert the AST into a list of sums of factors?"_, then the answer is _"by walking that tree in the proper order and printing the nodes in the appropriate format"_. If you want to know how to do **that**, then you'll have to show us a [mcve] containing such an AST, and the code you've written to walk the tree and print its nodes.

Comment: @Shmwel Of course. The AST representation allows any level of nesting. I will study your idea, I'm not sure how it applies, since in a given "level" you may have different operations that are treated differently, for instance (a*c+d) turns into { {a} {c, d} }

Comment: @CodeCaster Then, I would have to create a sample AST, but I'm afraid I cannot give any code, since I don't have a clue on how the proper walking order might be. Thanks for your constructive comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the shortest way to do this using **Math.NET Symbolics** from [Math.NET](https://www.mathdotnet.com/)

The key syntax to do so is like this:

```
SymbolicExpression.Parse("a*(b+c)").Expand().Summands().Select(x => x.Factors());
```

In it, I expand the expression and then I get the summands. For each of the summands, I get the factors.

To illustrate it better, consider the following expression:

```
a * (b + c* -d)
```

The sums of factors will be returned using this code:

```
var expression = "a*(b+c*-d)";
var sumsOfFactors = SymbolicExpression.Parse(expression)
    .Expand()
    .Summands()
    .Select(x => x.Factors());

var factorsStr = sumsOfFactors.Select(x => string.Join("\t", x));
var sumOfFactorsStr = string.Join("\n", factorsStr);
Console.WriteLine(sumOfFactorsStr);
```

That prints the sums of factors:

```
a   b
-1  a   c   d
```

That is exactly what I was looking for.